# Changing font-awesome icon on click without reloading the page

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

I have implemented font awesome in my project. Everything works fine.

So I have written some jqyuery to change the clicked font-awesome icon to another icon (empty square -> checked square) using this code:

```
    function checkTask(){
    // Dit loopke zodanig dat we dit doen voor alle taken
    $(".status").on('click' , function(a){
        a.preventDefault();
        var klikedItem = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        var Deid = klikedItem.slice(5, 6);
        console.log("idnvanelement" + Deid);
        if($(this).hasClass('fa-square-o')){
            localStorage.setItem("Status-" + Deid, 'klaar');
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("Status-" + Deid, 'nietklaar');
        }
    });

    var lengthNumber = localStorage.getItem('TaskNumber');
    for( i=1; i <= lengthNumber; i++) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("Status-" + i) == 'klaar'){
        $("#task-" + i + "> a.status").removeClass('fa-square-o').addClass('fa-check-square-o');
    }
    }
}
checkTask();
```

So what this code does, is, if the element is clicked, change the font-awesome class. But, the logo doesnt's change then. Therefore, I have to reload the page. But I don't want that.

How can I still change the font-awesome logo without reloading the page?
I have tried to use ajax, but without succes.
JSfiddle comming up if you guys like!

Comment: Instead of solely updating the local storage, you should also include `.addclass()` so the classes can be swapped live, or on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this:

```
    function checkTask(){
    // Dit loopke zodanig dat we dit doen voor alle taken
    $(".status").on('click' , function(a){
        a.preventDefault();
        var klikedItem = $(this).parent().attr('id');
        var Deid = klikedItem.slice(5, 6);
        console.log("IDvanelement" + Deid);
        if($(this).hasClass('fa-square-o')){
            localStorage.setItem("Status-" + Deid, 'klaar');
            $("#task-" + Deid + "> a.status").removeClass('fa-square-o').addClass('fa-check-square-o');
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("Status-" + Deid, 'nietklaar');
            $("#task-" + Deid + "> a.status").removeClass('fa-check-square-o').addClass('fa-square-o');
        }
    });

    var lengthNumber = localStorage.getItem('TaskNumber');
    for( i=1; i <= lengthNumber; i++) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("Status-" + i) == 'klaar'){
        $("#task-" + i + "> a.status").removeClass('fa-square-o').addClass('fa-check-square-o');
    }
    }
}
checkTask();
```